# Using multiple frameworks | DayCQ + Spring + Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm, jdbctemplate, aem

We're in the process of redesigning a large application (web-portal). We are suppose to use existing database that they have used for their old application. Now we are planning to use CQ for hosting the pages and supporting authoring on those pages.

So as we have closed on CQ option, question comes to integrate CQ with some external frameworks like Spring (to use JDBCTemplate) or Hibernate framework to access data from database. I have following options:

1. Either integrate CQ with hibernate framework to leverage caching, transaction management, data object mapping etc. But catch is hibernate can only be use to access data not for other purposes like making RESTful calls that we require too.
2. Or integrate CQ with spring framework to leverage JDBCTemplate to access data and also spring can help me with caching, transaction management, making RESTful calls but catch is that using JDBCtemplate will cause following problems

   a. LOC will increase and the code will be hard to maintain

   b. Query strings are hard to maintain in case if change in table takes place
3. Or use both and leverage advantages of both frameworks wherever required.

**Should I look forward to integrate CQ with both frameworks. If yes then question arises that what problem it will cause in terms of:**

```
- Ease of Use 
- Productivity 
- Maintainability
- Stability
- Performance
- Ease of Troubleshooting
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's data integration that you're after, CQ5 is based on Apache Sling which allows for accessing arbitrary data sources via its ResourceProvider mechanism. This was originally a read-only mechanism but read-write functionality was recently added.

Comment: Will it provide **caching** solution (I don't think so) or we need to explicitly write some logic for it?